# Uninitialized initializer constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I created a settings.rb file under the initializers folder containing values I need initialized once the application starts. However, on running rails s I get a "Uninitialized contant Settings(NameError)

Settings.rb

```
Settings.defaults[:single_phase] = 500
Settings.defaults[:three_phase]  = 300
```

I created the migration to accompany it already and the view.

Where is the problem?

Comment: better u can use application_settings file to do this like in application_settings file set your key value pair as key: value and use any where in your app like APP_SETTINGS['key'] => value

Comment: Can you elaborate more, will that solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your config/application_settings.rb

```
development:
  single_phase: 200
```

and use it anywhere in your app

```
APP_SETTINGS['single_phase']
```

which returns 200

Answer (score 0):

At the time initializers run they do not have access to the model (is it a model?).

If it isn't a model, you can do the following:

```
SETTINGS = {}
SETTINGS[:single_phase] = 500
```

However I feel like the [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem might be helpful for what you are trying to do.

You can also add arbitrary settings in the application.rb and environment files.