# Rails uninitialized constant in initializers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've taken over a working Rails 3 app from an offshore supplier and rails console is failing at this line:

```
 Settings.defaults[:processing_fee] = '0.99'
```

in the file config/initializers/settings.rb

I've compared this file with what is in git blame and it matches. I've removed the contents of this file and it runs so it doesn't like this line. Reading on SO I've made the filename and constant Singular. Following another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609169/uninitialized-initializer-constant) I created another file in config/application_settings.rb. The constant could not be found in console. Moving it to /initializers yielded on rails console

```
/Users/sam/apps/tickat/config/initializers/application_settings.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant SETTINGS (NameError)
```

from this content:

```
 SETTINGS[:processing_fee] = '0.99'
```

It appears that something about my environment is not accepting my constants here. I first noticed this pushing to Heroku and can replicate this error in development in console. I've asked around and am stuck. I'm sure it's something I goofed on, sam

Comment: You could try adding `SETTINGS ||= {}` before that line. Your error is telling you that you're trying to set a key/value pair on a hash that doesn't exist yet. The `||=` operator sets SETTINGS to an empty hash if it hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: yes, what is Settings ? A class? A Hash? It might be that someone forgot to commit a file in your repo, In this case, you need to reverse engineer Settings. I would make it an empty class and add class method .settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that someone forgot to commit a file in the repo of your application.

If this is the case, and you can't get the file from the author, you need to reverse engineer Settings. I would make it an empty module:

```
module Settings

  def self.defaults
     @defaults ||= {}
  end

end
```

And see how far you can get, before you get more errors...

EDIT: You can see in the console how this Hash is initalized:

```
irb(main):008:0> Settings.defaults
=> {}
irb(main):010:0> Settings.defaults[:a] = 1
=> 1
irb(main):011:0> Settings.defaults
=> {:a=>1}
```

Comment: No error yet, but no constants were added. Would I add :processing_fee = '0.99' as a member of that empty array? unsure.

Comment: The trick here is that you let the initializer set the defaults. It depends what you want, and where the defaults are coming from, but so far it looks like your applications expects a hash at Settings.defaults